# connection string pulled from database but is not working as it should with the traditional methods. May I have an extra thing in it?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, connection-string

I Have an oracle connection string for vb.net/XML that I am having some trouble to properly get working.  Is there something that I am doing wrong?  and the server is not immediately accessible to me, so testing is not always an option.  I atleast need to make sure that it is formatted correctly etc...

```
  providerName="oracle.dataAccess"
    connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcp.world)(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=XXXXXXXXX.XXXX.XXX.pvt)(Port=XXXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PXXXXXXF))(GLOBAL_NAME=PXXXXXXF.world))OK (280 msec);User Id=username;Password=password" />-->
```

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: There is a good site for connection strings; the Oracle-related section is at [www.connectionstrings.com/oracle](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/).

Comment: The error I get is TNS : could not resolve the connect Identifier specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually much easier than what you've got there.  That looks like a cut and paste from a tnsnames file.  Just explictly declare your entities:

```
User Id=user;Password=password;Server=server;Direct=True;Sid=sid;Port=1234
```

Better yet, if your provider has StringBuilder, let it do the heavy lifting:

```
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder sb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        sb.Server = "server";
        sb.Port = 1234;
        sb.Sid = "sid";
        sb.UserId = "user";
        sb.Password = "password";
        sb.Direct = true;

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(sb.ToString());
```

You may want to use Service Name in lieu of SID.  It just depends.

Comment: I tried it like that, but it didn't like any of the definitions.

Comment: What provider are you using?

Comment: Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.2.0 and its in a VB.net(4)

Comment: I assume that is ODP.net?  I saw your comment above about the error message.  That seems to imply it is trying to use tnsnames.  Direct=true is supposed to bypass that.  You definitely specifiec direct=true?  Have you tried connection directly through code rather than the xml?